# Searching in table view problem

Tags: iphone

Iam trying to searching data in the table view......

```
-(void)searchTableView{
    NSString *searchText=searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//  for (NSDictionary *dictionary in djList) {
//      NSLog(@"NSDictionary value is%@",dictionary);
////        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@""];
////        [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
//  }
    for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray) {
        NSRange titleResultsRange=[sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (titleResultsRange.length>0) {
        [copyListArray addObject:sTemp];
        }
    }
    [searchArray release];
    searchArray=nil;
}
```

There is problem in my commented lines....

I dont know what to do with ObjectForkKey:@"";

Is any other way out to work on this...... with out using NSDictionary....

@thanks in advance.

Comment: My be you can add the djList to see what is in it. What is the structure of the djList?

Comment: djListis NSMutableArray..... to have dj name's.... example:alexandro benzer mark

Comment: And in this NSMutableArray you have fill it with NSDictionary? And you want to see if an the searchBar.text is in one of these Dictionary? If so you can filter the NSMutableArray with an NSPredicate.

Comment: @Terente i am new to NSPredicate i dont know how to work on that ... can you help me out

Comment: @Terente i do awaiting for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of NSPredicate

```
 NSPredicate *annotationPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Latitudine = %@)AND(Longitudine = %@)AND(Name = %@) ",latitudeString,longitudeString,name];


SMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sourceArray];
[myArray filterUsingPredicate:annotationPredicate];
```

The dictionary from the array must have the keys from array in this case "Latitudine", "Longitudine", "Name".

NSpredicate doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html). And look at the sample codes there.

Take a look at [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doc

```
- (void)filterUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)searchTableView{
    NSString *searchText=searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//  for (NSDictionary *dictionary in djList) {
//      NSLog(@"NSDictionary value is%@",dictionary);
////        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@""];
////        [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
//  }
    [searchArray addObject:@"Alexandro"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"Beatzz"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"Cat"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"Chucky"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"DJ Cat"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"DJ Kuiken"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"Dj Michel"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"Dj Navarro"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"Dj Peter"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"Dj Wily - Waxfiend"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"Himself"];
    [searchArray addObject:@"janery - Chucky - Waxfiend"];

    for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray) {
        NSRange titleResultsRange=[sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (titleResultsRange.length>0) {
        [copyListArray addObject:sTemp];
        }
    }
    [searchArray release];
    searchArray=nil;
}`enter code here`
```

It iam adding statically its working fine...............

the same addobjects are in my djlist array... which is nsmutableArray....

so i added directly searchArray=djlist...... its went ugly. crash......